# How to check if each objects in array contains certain value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I need to check if each object in array contains a certain same value.
I could do it with for loop, but i was wondering is it possible to do it with one line of code.
Let's say I have objects

```js
    employees = [
           {
            n: 'case 1',
            date: '2021-05-4',
            id: '123',
            user: [{name: 'Vlad', id: '1'}, {name: 'Misha', id: '2'}],
            isPresent : true,
           },
           {
            caseName: 'case 2',
            date: '2021-05-4',
            id: '123',
            user: [{name: 'Alina', id: '3'}, {name: 'Alex', id: '4'}],
            isPresent : true,
           },
           {
            caseName: 'case 3',
            date: '2021-05-4',
            id: '123',
            user: [],
            isPresent : true,
           },
        ]
```

And my task is to check if all employees are present, so I need to get `true` if `isPresent` property assigned `true` for each object.
But have to do it with one live something like

```
let employeesPresent = employees(item => item.isPresent === true); ​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `every` method of array, which tests if all item in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function:

```
let employeesPresent = employees.every(item => item.isPresent === true); ​
```

(Note that your are using `isPesent` prop in your array declaration but `isPresent` in your function)